# How to give an initial value to textBox?

Tags: winforms, textbox

I want my C# program to have initial values for its `textboxes`. For example, in one of the `textboxes`, it should say `"Please enter your name"`.

When you click (or tabStop) on the `textbox`, the initial value should disappear and the user will be able to enter their input to the `textbox`.

I can do all this with `click_event`, but using this method the initial text would not have less opacity. How am I able to achieve this?

Comment: ASP.net, Winforms, WPF, Silverlight...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I finally did it:

```
Boolean first_time_click = true;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            textBox1.Text = "Enter the Text";
        }

private void For_First_Click()
        {
            if (first_time_click)
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.ForeColor = textBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            }
            first_time_click = false;
        }

private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            For_First_Click();
        }
```

Comment: Instead of first_time_click you can use the TextBox.Modified property which becomes true only after the user has modified a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about winform (tabstop) you have to handle it within the event key-press. you can use the below code:

```
TextBox1.Select(0, TextBox1.Text.Length);
```

this will select the text and window will remove it for you as soon as the user start to typing

you can use the same code to have this behavior also for TabStop

Comment: And what about the initial text looking like less opacitied?

Comment: this is a different matter: you have to Override the OnPaint event of the TextBox

Comment: Be careful when explicity setting colors in Windows applications. If someone is using a non-standard color scheme, you're going to mess them up. You can, however, use one of the default system colors like the Disabled Text color or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the Textbox's .Text property and use GotFocus event to clear the box when the person clicks (or tabs) into it to start typing.

Always remember that there are more ways than the mouse to navigate a form, so use the GotFocus event to determine when the user enters a control, and use the Validated event to determine when they've changed data and exited the control.

Answer (score -1):

For this type of effect you need java script.Because java script provide you functionality of mouse hover and mouse out these are the functions which provide you the same functionality which u seeing in this page of search bar. If you need code reply me i can give you.

Comment: we are talking about winform here