# How to make if statement for multiple elements? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I am using VS2017 and C# on Windows Forms.

I'm creating a little tool and I need some assistance.

I have 10 text boxes, names textGame1, textGame2, textGame3, etc etc

[image]

I want to create code, in which if the any of the text boxes are empty, then it will replace the textbox text to "EMPTY".

I could easily do

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textGame1.Text))
{
    textGame1.Text = "EMPTY";
}
```

However I would have to create 10 of those for each text box.

Is there a simpler way, than to create 10 of these IF statements?

Comment: To be clear, do you want "if any of the text boxes are empty set all text boxes to 'EMPTY'" or "if any of the text boxes are empty set that particular text box to 'EMPTY'"?

Comment: do this using the `Controls` class or do it with a lamda

Comment: @p.s.w.g your second point is correct.

Comment: This is how you can do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433854/how-to-give-an-initial-value-to-textbox

Comment: New program, vs 2017, WinForms. Nostalgic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a collection to store each text box you want to manipulate. You can do this by hand:

```
var textBoxes = new[] { textGame1, textGame2, textGame3, ... };
```

Or using the [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) collection (a little Linq can help):

```
var textBoxes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => (TextBox)Controls[$"textGame{i}"]);
```

Or if you need to search all children recursively, use the [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) method:

```
var textBoxes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => (TextBox)(Controls.Find($"textGame{i}", true)[0]));
```

Now, simply use a `foreach`:

```
foreach(var tb in textBoxes)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
    {
        tb.Text = "EMPTY";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This method looks the best for other tasks I need to do too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic code:

```
            const string baseName = "textBox";
            var names = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => baseName + x.ToString()).ToList();

            var tbxs = names.Select(name => this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault()).Where(x=> x != null).ToList();
            foreach (var txt in tbxs) {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
                {
                    txt.Text = "EMPTY";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your "own" textbox with a placeholder feature:

```
public class PlaceHolderTextBox : TextBox
{
    bool isPlaceHolder = true;
    string _placeHolderText;
    public string PlaceHolderText {
        get { return _placeHolderText; }
        set {
            _placeHolderText = value;
            setPlaceholder();
        }
    }

    //when the control loses focus, the placeholder is shown
    private void setPlaceholder()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text)) {
            this.Text = PlaceHolderText;
            this.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            this.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            isPlaceHolder = true;
        }
    }

    //when the control is focused, the placeholder is removed
    private void removePlaceHolder()
    {
        if (isPlaceHolder) {
            this.Text = "";
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            this.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
            isPlaceHolder = false;
        }
    }
    public PlaceHolderTextBox()
    {
        GotFocus += removePlaceHolder;
        LostFocus += setPlaceholder;
    }
}
```

Credit for code: https://gntheprogrammer.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-add-placeholder-in-windows-forms.html

I just converted it from VB  ;)